# How to upgrade maven's version from 3.1.x to 3.3.9 under Mac OX?

Tags: java, maven

I maven version 3.1.1 of this machine is that when I upgraded to version 3.3.9, when I execute no matter what kind of maven command will get the following error message:

```
Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.
```

like this:
[image]

#### Environmental Information

- Java version: 1.8.0_40
- OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.1", arch: "x86_64"
- Apache Maven 3.3.9

Comment: Updating is real simple. Delete the old, unzip the new. Basically that's it.

Comment: Doing that will not magically update any environmental variables of course.

Comment: Just download the tar.gz untar it to the wished location and add the bin folder to your path....

Answer (score 0):

I am [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5830) to find the answer.

that follow:
In `~/.bashrc` /`~/.zshrc`(
If you are using zsh)  add a line inside`export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME"`

After completion of the addition result like this:

`export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          M2_HOME=/Users/liuxinyu/software/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9
export M2_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:${M2_HOME}/bin:${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${GROOVY_HOME}/bin`